Regularity of the eigenfunctions associated to perturbed laplacian on a compact manifold
Let $M$ be a closed manifold, I consider first order laplacian perturbation associated to a density $\rho \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ with $\rho > 0$ of the form :
$$
\Delta_{\rho} f = \Delta f + \langle \nabla \log \rho, \nabla f \rangle.
$$
It is well known that if $\rho =1$ we have an hilbert basis of $L^2(dx)$ given by the eigenfunctions $(\phi_i)_i$ such that
$$
\Delta \phi_i = - \lambda_i \phi_i.
$$
If we take the perturbed laplacian we have once again an hilbert basis for $L^2(\rho dx)$ given by the eigenfunctions associated to $\Delta_\rho$ :
$$
\Delta_\rho \phi_i(\rho) = - \lambda_i (\rho) \phi_i(\rho).
$$
My question is, do we have any regularity on these eigenfunctions ? For example if we take $\rho_t$ such that
$$
\partial_t \rho_t = -\Delta_{\mu_t} \psi \rho_t,\quad \rho_0 = \rho,
$$
with $\psi \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$, can we compute $\partial_t \phi_i(\rho_t)$ ? It looks like this is about perturbation theory of kato but it is really hard to find results about it.
Thank you !
